# Error in spring xsd

Tags: spring, apache-camel

I am creating a apache-camel spring dsl application.
In the camel-config.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">
```

This is showing error
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - Referenced file contains errors (http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd). For more information, right click on the message 
     in the Problems View and select "Show Details..."
    - Start tag of element

on show details

s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements other than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw 'Error'.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have more than just this piece of xml, I bet your error is in some invalid xml you have typed yourself. There is plenty of Spring + Camel XML examples out there you can take look at, that works, for example:

- https://github.com/camelinaction/camelinaction/blob/master/chapter2/spring/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/camel-context.xml

Comment: Hi claus,thanks for the response.this problem is not occurring at the time of a java project...when i am trying to build a web app (by war packaging) this is showing the above error.

Comment: And deploying the war is working fine...only the error is coming in eclipse.